# Reshape long to wide and keep duplicated rows

Tags: r, reshape

For the given data set, i want to convert my data set from long format to wide format. I have used reshape function to do so.

```
id  status      timestamp   
1   assigned   2017-01-02  
1   done       2017-01-03  
1   locked     2017-01-04   
2   assigned   2017-01-02   
2   done       2017-01-03  
2   assigned   2017-01-03  
2   done       2017-01-04 
2   locked     2017-01-05  
3   assigned   2017-01-02  
3   done       2017-01-03 
3   locked     2017-01-04 
...

# reshape function to convert long format to Wide.
temp <- reshape(temp, idvar = "id", timevar = "status", direction = "wide")
```

Results:

`id   timestamp.assigned   timestamp.done    timestamp.locked`
`1        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`
`2        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-05`
`3        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`

when I do this it removes some of rows, for e.g: for id 2, there are multiple rows match for `status=assigned`, it takes the first row.

How can I convert to wide without removing rows. Basically, I don't want to lose any data.

Expected results:
`id   timestamp.assigned   timestamp.done    timestamp.locked`
`1        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`
`2        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-05`
`2        2017-01-03         2017-01-04          2017-01-05`
`3        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`

or

`id   timestamp.assigned   timestamp.done    timestamp.locked`
`1        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`
`2        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          NA`
`2        2017-01-03         2017-01-04          2017-01-05`
`3        2017-01-02         2017-01-03          2017-01-04`

Comment: What is the use of the duplicated rows, anyway?

Comment: What do you expect as your answer?

Comment: @Onyambu I have updated the description and added the expected results.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I need it because the status can go back to assigned again. The timestamps are different and hence need to calculate the turn around time between statuses.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. `cumsum()`

[Esther's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706021/3817004) to number each new assignment is the way to go.

However, R already has the `cumsum()` function which can be used for this purpose:

```
temp$key <- cumsum(temp$status == "assigned")
reshape(temp, idvar = c("key", "id"), timevar = "status", direction = "wide")
```

> ```
>    id key timestamp.assigned timestamp.done timestamp.locked
> 1:  1   1         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
> 2:  2   2         2017-01-02     2017-01-03             <NA>
> 3:  2   3         2017-01-03     2017-01-04       2017-01-05
> 4:  3   4         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
> ```

#### 2. Grouped `cumsum()`

Although this solves the OP's original problem, `key` just numbers *all* assignments across *all* `id`s. In case the OP prefers to have the assignments numbered individually for each `id` we need to apply `cumsum()` grouped by `id`.

One way to accomplish this is using `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, key := cumsum(status == "assigned"), by = id]
dcast(temp, id + key ~ status, value.var = "timestamp")
```

> ```
>    id key   assigned       done     locked
> 1:  1   1 2017-01-02 2017-01-03 2017-01-04
> 2:  2   1 2017-01-02 2017-01-03       <NA>
> 3:  2   2 2017-01-03 2017-01-04 2017-01-05
> 4:  3   1 2017-01-02 2017-01-03 2017-01-04
> ```

`dcast()` is a replacement of base R's `reshape(..., direction = "wide")` function which is available from the `reshape2` and `data.table` packages.

#### 3. Grouped `cumsum()` *on-the-fly*

The formula interface of `data.table`'s `dcast()` accepts also expressions. With this, it is not necessary to modify `temp` by appending a `key` column *before* reshaping. Instead, this can be accomplished on-the-fly *while* reshaping:

```
dcast(temp, id + ave(key <- status == "assigned", id, FUN = cumsum) ~ 
        paste0("timestamp.", status))
```

> ```
>    id key timestamp.assigned timestamp.done timestamp.locked
> 1:  1   1         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
> 2:  2   1         2017-01-02     2017-01-03             <NA>
> 3:  2   2         2017-01-03     2017-01-04       2017-01-05
> 4:  3   1         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
temp <- fread(
  "id  status      timestamp   
1   assigned   2017-01-02  
1   done       2017-01-03  
1   locked     2017-01-04   
2   assigned   2017-01-02   
2   done       2017-01-03  
2   assigned   2017-01-03  
2   done       2017-01-04 
2   locked     2017-01-05  
3   assigned   2017-01-02  
3   done       2017-01-03 
3   locked     2017-01-04 ")
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to add a variable that gave a unique value for each new assignment. Then you could use that to shape your data

```
i <- 0

temp$key <- sapply(temp$status, function(x) {
  if(x == "assigned") {i <<- i+1; i}
  else {i}
})

temp

   id   status  timestamp key
1   1 assigned 2017-01-02   1
2   1     done 2017-01-03   1
3   1   locked 2017-01-04   1
4   2 assigned 2017-01-02   2
5   2     done 2017-01-03   2
6   2 assigned 2017-01-03   3
7   2     done 2017-01-04   3
8   2   locked 2017-01-05   3
9   3 assigned 2017-01-02   4
10  3     done 2017-01-03   4
11  3   locked 2017-01-04   4

temp2 <- reshape(temp, idvar = c("key", "id"), timevar = "status", direction = "wide")

temp2

  id key timestamp.assigned timestamp.done timestamp.locked
1  1   1         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
4  2   2         2017-01-02     2017-01-03             <NA>
6  2   3         2017-01-03     2017-01-04       2017-01-05
9  3   4         2017-01-02     2017-01-03       2017-01-04
```

Comment: Good approach, but the `cumsum()` function already does what you want: `temp$key <- cumsum(temp$status == "assigned")`